# Memory utilization by C pipe

Tags: c, pipe, aix

Is there a way I can find out exact memory consumption by a PIPE opened by my process. I can run svmon with the pid on AIX and tried to map the segment with the PIPE utilization, but so far I am unable to, as the size of memory - which I think should match to PIPE utilization [from my svmon o/p corresponding to the process] - doesn't match to the maximum buffer size of a PIPE. Is there any way to check that?

Comment: can you post the code you use, as far as I can see calling pipe() is creating kernel objects, not userspace objects so It may be impossible to see any increases in the process memory use.

Comment: The capacity of a pipe is usually pretty small (classically, it was just 5 KiB, but it may be a bit larger now; POSIX only mandates 4 KiB as the minimum acceptable capacity).  So the memory cost is normally barely noticeable.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, my idea was a PIPE can potentially grow until PIPE_BUF [limits.h] is reached, considering no reader is started. This value varies from system to system, for example in my AIX system it is - PIPE_BUF        32768. Upto this far it is pretty simple as I guess. Now consider I am opening a 42mb file and pushing 1024 bytes with each write to pipe, it will write at max 32KB as long as read process is not initiated [You can put a sleep of 30 sec in read process]. As soon as the read happens again write starts and continues as long as the BUF is not reached.

Comment: This I can produce each time. But my question was if there is any way I can map this 32KB memory space in svmon output for the process. So far I am not successful.

Comment: in the kernel, there is usually a limited number of pipes allowed at any one time and the kernel pipe buffers are pre-allocated.  So opening a pipe makes no difference in the kernel size.

Comment: My question is this memory is in which user space? How does a user process gets access to it, if the memory segment is not owned by the user. However small - what is the preallocated size of it? What are the segments of these buffers? [I am just trying to find through svmon output on AIX].